# SpringBoot Mockito: when..thenReturn giving an exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, exception, mockito

So, currently, I'm testing on a Service class

This is my `ConvertService.java`

```
@Service
public class ConvertService {

  private final NetworkClient networkClient; //NetworkClient is a Service too

  private final ConvertUtility convertUtility; 

  public ConvertService(Network networkClient) {
    convertUtility = ConvertFactory.of("dev", "F");
    this.networkClient = networkClient

  }


  public Response convert(Request request) {

    User user = networkClient.getData(request.getId()); //User is POJO class
    Context context = convertUtility.transform(request.getToken()) //getToken returns a String
    //Context is a normal Java 

  }

}
```

This is my  `ConvertServiceTest.java`

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
class ConvertServiceTest {

  @MockBean
  private NetworkClient networkClient;

  @Mock
  ConvertUtility convertUtility;

  private ConvertService convertService;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    convertService = new ConvertService(networkClient);
  }

  private mockMethod() {
    Request request = Request(1000);
    User user = new User("user1");
    Context context = new Context();

    when(networkClient.getData(anyLong())).thenReturn(user);
    when(convertUtility.transform(any(String.class)).thenReturn(context);
     
     Response response = convertService.convert(request);  //it throws me an exception here
    }
  }
```

`convertService.convert(request);` throws an exception

pointing inside `convertUtility.transform(request.getToken())`

I'm not sure why it's processing everything from `transform` method, when I wrote
`when(convertUtility.transform(any(String.class)).thenReturn(context);`

Can anyone please help?

EDIT: `ConvertUtility` is a read-only library

Comment: you do understand that you created your `ConvertUtility` inside the constructor of `TestService` and as such your `@Mock` would not do anything?

Comment: You're mixing quite a lot of topics here. I assume your intent is to write a basic unit test for your `ConvertService` class. However, with `@SpringBootTest` you're populating your entire application context. I can recommend this [article for a basic overview of testing Spring Boot applications](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-unit-and-integration-testing-overview/). Also, make sure to understand the [difference between `@Mock` and `@MockBean`](https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/). Furthermore, you mix JUnit 4 (`@RunWith`) and 5 (`BeforeEach`).

Comment: @Eugene Sorry, I'm new to SpringBoot. I didn't know that. Where else can I create it?

Comment: @reickpil Thanks for that, I'll check it out.

Comment: that's fine, no big deal. you could move `convertUtility = ConvertFactory.of("dev", "F");` so that it becomes a `Service` too, and then inject it in the `ConvertService`: `public ConvertService(Network networkClient, ConvertFactory factory){....}`

Comment: @Eugene but it's a read-only library

Comment: look at the answer below - this is what I meant.

Comment: @Eugene What if I create the `ConvertUtility` instance locally inside the convert method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your public constructor, you're using a static factory method to get an instance of the `ConvertUtility`. You'd have to mock the static `ConvertUtility.of()` method to work with a mock during your test.

While [Mockito is able to mock static methods](https://rieckpil.de/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito-java-kotlin/), I'd recommend refactoring (if possible) your class design and accepting an instance of `ConvertUtility` as part of the public constructor:

```
@Service
public class ConvertService {

  private final NetworkClient networkClient; //NetworkClient is a Service too
  private final ConvertUtility convertUtility;

  public ConvertService(Network networkClient, ConvertUtility convertUtility) {
    this.convertUtility = convertUtility
    this.networkClient = networkClient

  }
}
```

With this change, you can easily mock the collaborators of your `ConvertService` when writing unit tests:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ConvertServiceTest {

   @Mock
   private NetworkClient networkClient;

   @Mock
   private ConvertUtility convertUtility;

   @InjectMocks
   private ConvertService convertService;

   @Test // make sure it's from org.junit.jupiter.api
   void yourTest() {


   }
}
```

Comment: I can't really refactor  `ConvertUtility ` class because it's a read-only library. Sorry, I just added it to the question

Comment: What if I create the `ConvertUtility` instance locally inside the convert method?

Comment: If you're creating the `ConvertUtility` inside using a static factory method, then you have to use [Mockito's static mocking feature](https://rieckpil.de/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito-java-kotlin/).